# VB.net Passing value of Array 1, to Array 2

Tags: arrays, vb.net, encryption, modulo

so i have this code, and i need to pass the value of array1 to array2,
but the value of array2 should be array1 + (key Mod 255) where key is put by the user

```
    Private Sub mod_Btn_enc_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mod_Btn_enc.Click
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    If mod_TB_key.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Pls Input Modulo Key Value", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        modKey = mod_TB_key.Text
    End If

    modModulo = modKey Mod 255 'formula
    mod_TB_mod.Text = modModulo 'i used this to show that it is working
'modbyte = array 1
'modconverted = array2
    For Each i As Integer In modByte
        counter += 1
        modConverted(counter - 1) = modByte(i - 1) + (modModulo) 'formula used
    Next i
    mod_Tb_enc.Text = String.Join(" ", modConverted) 'show the array in textbox
```

here is my interface

[image]

Comment: And your problem/question is...?

Comment: `For Each i As Integer In modByte
     counter += 1
        1modConverted(counter - 1) = modByte(i - 1) + (modModulo)
Next i `
        
is this wrong? and what's wrong with it? modconverted doesnt show in the textbox

Comment: @dadadadaryl what does show in the textbox?  It's a bit weird that you're indexing into modByte by using a value you've taken out of modByte.

Comment: @phoog sorry, i don't have deep knowledge in arrays. 

modconverted(0) = ((value of modbyte(0)) + (modModulo))

it should be that way.

Comment: @dadadadaryl your actual code gives modConverted(0) = (value of modByte(value of modByte(0) - 1)) + modModulo, because in the first iteration of the loop, `i` has the value of `modByte(0)`.  In the second iteration of the loop, `i` is `modByte(1)` and so on.  That is, if modByte contains three elements, `{ 42, 7, 0 }` then the three values of `i` will be 42, then 7, then 0.

Comment: @phoog oh, now i know. thank you. i've managed to do it. thank you for your answer :)  i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

i've managed to do it this way.

```
For i = 0 To modByte.GetUpperBound(0)
        counter += 1
        ReDim Preserve modConverted(counter - 1)
        modConverted(counter - 1) = modByte(i) + (modModulo)
    Next
```

thanks for explaining @phoog